# How to compare two table value using if condition in function of Postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
create or replace function  trace.get_latest_exception_custom_msg(id varchar)
returns varchar 
language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
msg varchar ;
begin
    
perform t1.message, t1.created_time from table_1 t1 where t1.id  = id order by t1.created_time desc limit 1; 

perform t2.message, t2.created_time from table_2 t2 where t2.id = id order by t2.created_time desc limit 1; 

if date(t1.created_time ) >= date(t2.created_time) then msg= t1.message;

elsif  d date(t1.created_time ) < date(t2.created_time) then msg= t1.message;
else msg =t1.message;

end if;


return msg;
end;
```

while i call this function it give error ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [store the result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) of the two SELECT queries into variables in order to be able to be able to use them in an IF statement.

Your `IF` statement is also a bit confusing as all three parts assign the same value to `msg`. I assume that you want to use `t2.message` at least in one case.

```
create or replace function  trace.get_latest_exception_custom_msg(p_id varchar)
  returns varchar 
language plpgsql
as 
$$
declare 
  t1_msg varchar;
  t1_created date;
  t2_msg varchar;
  t2_created date;
  msg varchar;
begin

  select t1.message, t1.created_time::date
    into t1_msg, t1_created
  from table_1 t1 
  where t1.id = p_id 
  order by t1.created_time desc 
  limit 1; 

  select t2.message, t2.created_time::date
    into t2_msg, t2_created
  from table_2 t2 
  where t2.id = p_id 
  order by t2.created_time desc 
  limit 1; 
    
  if t1_created >= t2_created then 
    msg := t1_msg;
  elsif t1_created < t2_created then 
    msg := t2_msg; --<< ??? 
  else 
    -- this can only happen if one (or both) of the DATEs is NULL. 
    msg := t1_msg; 
  end if;

  return msg;
end; 
$$
```

Comment: if in case need to compar datetime value then what type will be for example: used.t2.created_time has date and time both

Comment: Then you need to use `timestamp`